# LocationClient requirements in manifest file

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Okay I'm using LocationClient API but without viewing Maps in my application. All I'm doing is updating current locations to the server. Of course the last 6 hours locations.

1)Should the following permission be there?

```
 <permission
        android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

2)should the API key still be there?

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCxXOFev03HX4vr6ZGfd0983noouy3wt0g" />
```

3)Should I use this permission as well?

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need those permissions if you aren't using maps. You only need location permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```